# cmake git clone via ssh fails on windows with Host key verification failed

Tags: git, ssh, cmake, ssh-keys

i have a C program which is build using cmake unter linux and macOS fine. I tried to cross-compile it under windows with cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" .. but I ran into a strange error.

Within the cmake file I am cloning several libraries to build my main program via ssh.

However, the clone process always fails with the error message:

```
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I tried to add my ssh key with ssh-add to the ssh agent but this does not solve my problem.

Does anyone has an explanation and solution for me?

Update: I can clone the repos from CLI under windows without any problem, the error only occurs when using cmake.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+Host+key+verification+failed

Comment: The problem is with **host** key, not user key. The solution is `ssh-keyscan <host> >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts` where `<host>` is a placeholder for your real host.

Comment: Hi I know it is with host key and I did the ssh-keyscan but still the error remains the same. I am a linux and MacOS user and not very familiar with Windows but need to make the project buildable under windows and now struggling at this point. I can checkout the repos via cli without any problem, it only fails using cmake.

Comment: You said about your ssh key and `ssh-add`, said nothing about `ssh-keyscan`. "*…the error only occurs when using cmake.*" Different user? Different `HOME`? Two different `ssh`, `cmake` or `git` using the wrong one?

Comment: I used ssh-keyscan but this does not solve the problem. I use the same user, same shell, same home. That's what drives me crazy because I cannot see the difference. The only think I can think of is that cmake don't use the shell environment and therefore does not see the known hosts file etc.

Comment: "*…cmake don't use the shell environment and therefore does not see the known hosts file…*" Could be it; I don't know `cmake` good enough to help.